# Movie where an "infected person" tries to infect one of the leads by shoving a black octopus thing down their throat

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I’m looking for a movie I watched during the mid 2010’s. I don’t remember it well, as I was a small kid.

I only remember a specific scene where one of the "infected people" tries to infect one of the leads by shoving this octopus thing down their throat. It’s not *Alien* (1979) or a Facehugger. It looked like a black octopus, but it’s just tentacles and the mouth of the alien is in the middle, like a starfish.

Sorry for the non specific description, but it was when I was small.

Comment: Hi. Do you have any sense of how old the movie was when you watched it? Also, was it set on present day Earth? In the distant future? Another planet? A spaceship?

Answer (score 19):

Is this ***[The Hidden](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093185/)*** (1987)...?

> A cop and an FBI agent race for answers after law abiding people suddenly become violent criminals.

The plot centres on the hunt for an alien parasite that arrives on 20th century Earth and goes on a crime-spree, using several different people as host bodies.

The alien resembles an oversized black slug, but with multiple tendrils extending from its body, and transfers to and from each host body through the mouth.

> [image: Image of the alien parasite from "The Hidden" (1987).]
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*The Hidden* (1987)</sub>

Answer (score 6):

> I only remember a specific scene where one of the "infected people"
> tries to infect one of the leads by shoving this octopus thing down
> their throat.

This made me think instantly about the last scene of [Rec 2 (2009)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec_2). Here's the [scene](https://youtu.be/-IRRsteHTz0?t=311) (spoiler warning, also it's a disgusting thing to watch).
The date match, but it's not a sci-fi setting, and

> the creature is more of a worm than a octopus.

Comment: It's not shown at the last scene of Rec, but the last one of Rec 2. They are the same scene, but in Rec 2 last scene it's shown a longer and more complete cam recorder footage than the one shown in Rec.

Comment: @Piranna, you're right, I edited the post